# XML toprettyxml escapes quotes

Tags: android, python, xml, escaping

In Android strings documentation you can see this example (the point is, if you have double quotes around a string you don't need to escape single quotes).

```
<string name="good_example_2">"This'll also work"</string>
```

If I want to generate strings.xml with python it all works fine (expected result), until I use toprettyxml, which will turn it into

```
<string name="good_example_2">&quot;This'll also work&quot;</string>
```

I'm using prettify [like in this example](https://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html).

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom

def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")
```

`toprettyxml` escapes quotes. Any way to stop that from happening?

Comment: any solution to this issue