# Disable escaping when pretty-printing an XML with Python ElementTree and minidom

Tags: python, xml, escaping, elementtree

I'm trying to build an XML file using Python with ElementTree, then pretty-printing it using minidom following [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17402424/276451). The issue I'm facing is that when I generate a `SubElement`, if the string contains quotes, it gets escaped to `&quot;`.

The code is pretty simple:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
from xml.dom import minidom

def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element."""
    rough_string = et.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="\t")

top = et.Element("Base")
sub = et.SubElement(top, "Sub")
sub.text = 'Hello this is "a test" with quotes'

print(prettify(top))
```

And the generated XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Base>
  <Sub>Hello this is &quot;a test&quot; with quotes</Sub>
</Base>
```

Is there a way of avoiding escaping the quotes?

Comment: Looking at the ElementTree code I think the answer is negative. See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1073

Comment: It can be done with lxml, if you can use it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Python 3.8. Do you write the generated XML to a file?

Comment: writing the Sub-Elements contents as CDATA might help, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174890/how-to-output-cdata-using-elementtree

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot use lxml, I have to stick to standard libraries. I'm using Python 3.4, due to the operating system being a RHEL 7.x version. The output in the question is from printing the xml directly to stdout.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with Python 2.7 either. What exaclly does "printing the xml directly to stdout"? mean? Do you use `et.dump(top)`, `print(et.tostring(top))`, or what?

Comment: You're right @mzjn the issue is actually happening in the way I print the xml. I was using minidom to prettify the XML before printing it, sorry for omitting that. Looks like the escaping is added by minidom.

Comment: And that, therefore, directly turns this question into a literal duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145809/xml-toprettyxml-escapes-quotes

Comment: Here is the minidom code that does the escaping: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/xml/dom/minidom.py#L306

Comment: Related bug report: https://bugs.python.org/issue37374